# Why my bootstrap popover doesn't show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I create a **static popover** in bootstrap,
but it doesn't work

some of the html code:

```
<div class="container row-fluid" >
<div class="span8 offset2">
    <div class="hero-unit">
        <h1 class="hidden-phone">Heading</h1>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span5" style="margin-top:30px;">
                <div class="popover left" id="welcome">
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                    <h3 class="popover-title">To ALL:</h3>
                    <div class="popover-content">
                        <p>count and</p>                
                        <p>。。。</p>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <img src="img/welcome/1.jpg" class="img-circle img-polaroid pull-right hidden-phone" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="#">TEST NOW!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

all of my js code:

```
$('#welcome').popover();
```

Comment: Any errors? Are you sure its even calling in the js fie?

Comment: i don't receive any error msg in my firebug

Comment: you can see whole code on my web, just at the top of content of this question

Comment: One thing is your Image is not found..

Comment: the img dosen't matter...

Comment: You haven't specified where the content for the popover comes from.

Comment: @isherwood thank you, but this html code ( <div class="popover left" id="welcome"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title">To ALL:</h3><div class="popover-content">
                        <p>count and</p>                
                        <p>。。。</p>  
                    </div>
                </div>)is copied from bootstrap's official website

Answer (score 7):

I am giving an example code.

Html:

```
<span class="giverscore_tooltip">Example</span>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     $('.giverscore_tooltip').popover({
        trigger:'hover',
        content:'write a review, create a keyword, invite a friend, and more.',
        placement:'top'
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

I can see , what went wrong . The code you are referring to is generated when you  create a popover over a button .

Check JS fiddle with working button [Jsfiddle you can edit](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/DJtsa/4/)

Check in browser [Browser and test the button](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/DJtsa/4/show)
[image: screenshot of html generated]

Section 1:

```
<div class="popover left" ">
                <div class="arrow"></div>
                <h3 class="popover-title">To ALL:</h3>
                <div class="popover-content">
                    <p>count and</p>                
                    <p>。。。</p>  
                </div>
              </div>
```

So for example you want to create the above content in a popover , you will have to do the following :

```
<a id="pop" title="" data-content="<p>Content and</p><p> Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.</p>" data-placement="left" data-toggle="popover" class="btn" href="#" data-original-title="Popover on left" data-html="true">Try me</a>
```

So when you will click this button the above code in section 1 will generate . Also remember if you want to use html content set `data-html="true"`

Answer (score 1):

You must apply the popover function to the button, not the content.

```
$('.btn').popover();
```

This still doesn't completely solve the problem, since you haven't associated your content div with this button, but it's a start.

UPDATE: After gaining a better understanding of what the OP is after, I think it could be accomplished simply by showing the popover after it's initialized:

```
$(div#welcome').popover();
$('div#welcome').show();
```

This is a very roundabout way to do nothing more than style an element like a popover, however. It should really be done with CSS alone.

Comment: plz look at this: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers   official website said that it can be static and no need to bind to a button

Comment: I'm very familiar with that page, and I don't see anything like what you have.

Comment: I think I see where you're misunderstanding that page. The static popovers are there to show you what popovers look like, not how to implement them. Ignore the code used for those and look at the actual techniques below.

Comment: Here's the crucial bit: "No markup shown as popovers are generated from JavaScript and content within a data attribute."

Comment: the content of popover has even been hidden, you can see the code. Crtl-U

Comment: if so, what can the example page shows the popover and it is static?